# Finding Smallest Common Multiple

Tags: javascript

I want to find the smallest common multiple of the numbers in the array. For this I have come up with the following code. However, it doesn't seem to be working. It does when the last number is 22 but not 23. With 23 being the last number in the array, looks like that for loop gives infinity for some reason. The https://jsconsole.com/ website runs it fine and outputs the correct number but fcc.org and playcode.io sites don't output the correct result. The playcode.io gives this error "Infinity loop on line 4, char 0. You can increase loop timeout in settings" which refers to for loop. And yet https://js.do/ site runs the code fine and outputs the correct result.

Any idea why this might be happening.

```
let lcm = 0;
let arr = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
for(let i = 1; i <= arr.reduce((x,y) => x*y); i++) {
if((arr.every((n)=>{return (i % n === 0) ? true : false; }))) {
  lcm = i;
  break;
}
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine.

Comment: It is working fine

Comment: Off topic but a little reminder: `return (i % n === 0) ? true : false;` is equivalent to `return (i % n === 0);`

Comment: but fcc.org site does not output the correct result.. it returns zero.

Comment: They might limit computation power. How many iterations do you need for any tuple n,m